# How to swap contents inside a cell in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a list of 1000+ urls in an excel column and I want to edit the structure by swaping the position of the parameters

For example:

Original structure

Www.example.com/test.htm?name=John&age=21&city=London&unique_id=1425&dept=cs

Here, I want the parameter "unique_id" to be placed before the "age" parameter..

Expected structure

Www.example.com/test.htm?name=John&unique_I'd=1425&age=21&city=London&dept=cs

Is there a formula or method that I can run on that column

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a formula like below... but it has some quirky behaviour depending on the variability of your urls:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"&age=",MID(A1,FIND("&unique_id=",A1),FIND("&",A1&"&",FIND("&unique_id=",A1)+1)-FIND("&unique_id=",A1))&"&age="),MID(A1,FIND("&unique_id=",A1),FIND("&",A1&"&",FIND("&unique_id=",A1)+1)-FIND("&unique_id=",A1)),"",2)
```

So the core is:

- `MID(A1,FIND("&unique_id=",A1),FIND("&",A1&"&",FIND("&unique_id=",A1)+1)-FIND("&unique_id=",A1))` which extracts the `&unique_id=xxxxx` string
- We then `SUBSTITUTE` the existing `&age=` string with unique_id string with `&age=` stuck back on
- We then remove the second occurrence of the `&unique_id=xxxxx` string by substituting it with `""` - so if we have brought the unique_id forward in the url, we get rid of the original one

Doing this with VBA would be more robust - but it seemed like a nice formula challenge :-)